# Use the General Sibling Selector to naviagate through nested Elements

Tags: html, css

Hey i have a question about the General Sibling Selector.

First take a look at the Html:

```
<div id="layout-middle">
 <div id="Center">
   <a class="col Picture1">Titel1</a>
   <a class="col Picture2">Titel2</a>
   <a class="col Picture3">Titel3</a>
   <a class="col Picture4">Titel4</a>
   <a class="col Picture5">Titel5</a>
   <a class="col Picture6">Titel6</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #layout-middle {
  background: #d3d1ce url('Images/middle.jpg') top center repeat-x;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #777674;
}
 #Center {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: table;
}
.col {
 border: 1px solid #3E414A;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 width: 160px;
 height: 375px;
 padding-top: 16px;
 margin-top: -93px;
}

#bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 background-image: url('Images/bg-top.jpg');
 transition: .25s;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

#Bg is just a background-image behind all elements.

All Images look like this:

```
.Image1{
 background: url('Images/PictureXY.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
```

Now my question is when i hover for example picture1 how can i set the #bg background-image to a new one **without** Javascript only with CSS

Normally i would go like:

```
.col:hover ~ #bg{
  background-image:url('newimage.png')
}
```

but that doesn't work because of the nested elements.
I know i could do this easily with Javascript but my requirements say only HTML & CSS

It don't have to be a General Sibling Selector if you got something better let me know.

Comment: With your current html structure is not possible. Are you open to change html?

Comment: yes i'm open for everyhing that will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment with your current html structure is not possible. According to specs:

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences **share the same parent** in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

But with the following html you can:

```css
#layout-middle {
   background: #d3d1ce url('Images/middle.jpg') top center repeat-x;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #777674;
 }
 #Center {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: table;
 }
 .col {
   border: 1px solid #3E414A;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   width: 160px;
   height: 375px;
   padding-top: 16px;
   margin-top: -93px;
 }
 #bg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
   background-image: url('Images/bg-top.jpg');
   transition: .25s;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

.col:hover ~ #bg{
  background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97100&w=200&h=100')
}
```

```html
<div id="layout-middle">
  <div id="Center">
    <a class="col Picture1">Titel1</a>
    <a class="col Picture2">Titel2</a>
    <a class="col Picture3">Titel3</a>
    <a class="col Picture4">Titel4</a>
    <a class="col Picture5">Titel5</a>
    <a class="col Picture6">Titel6</a>
    <div id="bg"></div><!-- move div here -->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @MarvinKayx Glad that I helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS given the current structure.

The `.col` links are not siblings or children of the `#bg` div, so there is no CSS3 selector than can apply.

The only option is to move the `#bg` *into* the `#Center` div...then the general sibling selector will work.

Without changing the HTML structure, you will need javascript.